# BASH syntax error at line 1: `then' unmatched

Tags: linux, bash, solaris

```
eval: syntax error at line 1: `then' unexpected
```

Hi, I am having issues with this particular loop and couldn't find a solution to it, any ideas why?

```
getent passwd | cut -f1 -d":" | sort -n | uniq -c |\ while read x ; do [ -z "${x}" ] && break set - $x if [ $1 -gt 1 ]; then gids=`getent passwd |\ nawk -F: '($1 == n) { print $3 }' n=$2 | xargs`     echo "Duplicate Group Name ($2): ${gids}" fi done
```

Comment: You code has many errors.   Before asking a human for help, please run the code through [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/).  If there are errors there that you can't resolve, then ask a question here.

Comment: `break set - $x if [ $1 -gt 1 ]` runs the command `break` with many arguments.  It does not contain the beginning of an `if` statement.

Comment: @John1024 I ran it through there before asking the question here, the error is not helpful to what I am facing (because I don't understand it, hence I am asking a question..?). in the case of many errors, would you point it out rather then posting the link here, which will would allow me to improve the quality of the question?

Comment: One issue I see is the superfluous backslashes.  It looks like, at one point, the code was on several lines and those lines were merged into one, introducing many errors.  Did shellcheck not show those errors?  Or, did you run the multiline version there and merge it to one line here?

Comment: @John1024 Spellcheck gave me a issue that has no use whatsoever, it just had one error that states : "Parsing Stopped Here" and that did not help. I ran it on single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run the code through shellcheck and correct the errors which it shows (except for one problematic warning), the code will become:

```
getent passwd | cut -f1 -d":" | sort -n | uniq -c |
while read -r x ; do
  [ -z "${x}" ] && break
  set - $x
  if [ "$1" -gt 1 ]; then
    gids=$(getent passwd | nawk -F: '($1 == n) { print $3 }' n="$2" | xargs)
    echo "Duplicate Group Name ($2): ${gids}"
  fi
done
```

The code still seems to have issues, one of which is that it looks for duplicate *user* names but the print out claims that it found duplicate *group* names.

I would suggest replacing the above with:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '{c[$1]++; uids[$1]=uids[$1]" "$3} END{for (name in c) if (c[name]>1) printf "Duplicate User Name (%s):%s\n",name, uids[name]}'
```

#### How the awk code works

In the output of `getent passwd`, the user name will be in field 1 and the user ID will be in field 3.

- `c[$1]++; uids[$1]=uids[$1]" "$3`

  This counts the number of times that user name `$1` occurs and saves the count in array `c`.  It also saves the user ID, `$3`, associated with each name in array `uids`.
- `END{for (name in c) if (c[name]>1) printf "Duplicate User Name (%s):%s\n",name, uids[name]}`

  After we have finished processing getent's output, this looks for user names for which the count is greater than 1 and prints the info.

#### Multiline version of suggested code

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '
    {
        c[$1]++
        uids[$1] = uids[$1] " " $3
    } 

    END{
        for (name in c) 
           if (c[name]>1) 
               printf "Duplicate User Name (%s):%s\n", name, uids[name]
    }'
```

Comment: Looking at the replacement, instead of looping through like the previous , you directly use a counter to increase each appearance, which looks much neater and efficient! Will convert all my other commands to such a format, didn't think of it. Thanks :)